# symfony4 - What to use instead of Bundles?

Tags: bundle, symfony4

The `symfony4` [documentation states](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html) that you shouldn't use Bundles in your main code anymore:

> In Symfony versions prior to 4.0, it was recommended to organize your
> own application code using bundles. This is no longer recommended and
> bundles should only be used to share code and features between
> multiple applications.

Any ideas how I can organize my code instead?

I think about having 200 entities. When they live all on the same level inside the `Entity` dir... that's a f****ing chaos!

Maybe namespacing/subfoldering?

PS: In `django` I'd think in the term of an `app`.

Comment: You can look at DDD : Domain Driven Design :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, I think organize your entity by domain is a good solution. Like `Entity\Shop`, `Entity\Forum`. This is also applicable to controllers, views, etc